# Inverse Laplace problem using partition fraction

Tags: laplace-transform, partial-fractions

Hello I am solving inverse Laplace transform using partial fraction. The question is:

$$ X(s) = \frac{10(s+1)}{s(s^2+4s+8)} => \frac{10(s+1)}{s((s+2)^2+4)} $$

$$ \frac {C1} {s} + \frac{C2}{((s+2)+4)} + \frac{C3}{((s+2)^2+4)}  $$
for finding C1
$$ \frac{10(s+1)}{s((s+2)^2+4)} = \frac {C1} {s} + \frac{C2}{((s+2)+4)} + \frac{C3}{((s+2)^2+4)}  $$
Multiplying both side by $s$ and set $s=0$, we get
$C1=5/4$
for finding C3
$$ \frac{10(s+1)}{s((s+2)^2+4)} = \frac {C1} {s} + \frac{C2}{((s+2)+4)} + \frac{C3}{((s+2)^2+4)}  $$
Multiplying both side by $((s+2)^2+4)$ and set $s=-2$, we get
$C3=5$
For C2 I will take first derivative $X(s)$and Multiplying both side by $((s+2)^2+4)$ 
$$ \frac{d}{ds}[((s+2)^2+4) X(s)]  = \frac{d}{ds} \frac{10s}{s}$$
$$ \frac {s(10) - (10s + 10)*1} {s^2} $$
We set $s=-2$
I got $C2=-5/2$...

but the solution I have they said $C2 = -5/4$
Please can you tell where I did mistake?

Answer (score 1):

(BIG) HINT:

$$\mathcal{L}_{s}^{-1}\left[\frac{10(s+1)}{s(s^2+4s+8)}\right]_{(t)}=$$
$$\mathcal{L}_{s}^{-1}\left[\frac{5}{4s}-\frac{5(s-4)}{4(s^2+4s+8)}\right]_{(t)}=$$
$$\mathcal{L}_{s}^{-1}\left[\frac{5}{4s}\right]_{(t)}-\mathcal{L}_{s}^{-1}\left[\frac{5(s-4)}{4(s^2+4s+8)}\right]_{(t)}=$$
$$\frac{5}{4}\mathcal{L}_{s}^{-1}\left[\frac{1}{s}\right]_{(t)}-\frac{5}{4}\mathcal{L}_{s}^{-1}\left[\frac{s-4}{s^2+4s+8}\right]_{(t)}=$$
$$\frac{5}{4}\mathcal{L}_{s}^{-1}\left[\frac{1}{s}\right]_{(t)}-\frac{5}{4}\mathcal{L}_{s}^{-1}\left[\frac{s-4}{(s+2)^2+4}\right]_{(t)}=$$
$$\frac{5}{4}\mathcal{L}_{s}^{-1}\left[\frac{1}{s}\right]_{(t)}-\frac{5}{4}\mathcal{L}_{s}^{-1}\left[\frac{s}{(s+2)^2+4}-\frac{4}{(s+2)^2+4}\right]_{(t)}=$$
$$\frac{5}{4}\mathcal{L}_{s}^{-1}\left[\frac{1}{s}\right]_{(t)}-\frac{5}{4}\left(\mathcal{L}_{s}^{-1}\left[\frac{s}{(s+2)^2+4}\right]_{(t)}-\mathcal{L}_{s}^{-1}\left[\frac{4}{(s+2)^2+4}\right]_{(t)}\right)=$$
$$\frac{5}{4}\mathcal{L}_{s}^{-1}\left[\frac{1}{s}\right]_{(t)}-\frac{5}{4}\left(\mathcal{L}_{s}^{-1}\left[\frac{s}{(s+2)^2+2^2}\right]_{(t)}-\mathcal{L}_{s}^{-1}\left[\frac{2\cdot2}{(s+2)^2+2^2}\right]_{(t)}\right)=$$
$$\frac{5}{4}\mathcal{L}_{s}^{-1}\left[\frac{1}{s}\right]_{(t)}-\frac{5}{4}\left(\mathcal{L}_{s}^{-1}\left[\frac{s}{(s+2)^2+2^2}\right]_{(t)}-2\mathcal{L}_{s}^{-1}\left[\frac{2}{(s+2)^2+2^2}\right]_{(t)}\right)$$

Now use:

- $F\left(s\right)\to f(t)\Longrightarrow \frac{1}{s}\to1$
- $F\left(s\right)\to f(t)\Longrightarrow F(s-a)\to e^{at}f(t)$
- $F\left(s\right)\to f(t)\Longrightarrow F(s+a)\to e^{-at}f(t)$
- $F\left(s\right)\to f(t)\Longrightarrow \frac{\omega}{s^2+\omega^2}\to\sin(\omega t)$
- $F\left(s\right)\to f(t)\Longrightarrow \frac{s}{s^2+\omega^2}\to\cos(\omega t)$

Comment: with this way I got 
$\frac{5}{4}u(t) - \frac{5}{4} e^{-2t}cos(2t) + \frac{5}{4} e^{-2t}sin(2t)u(t)$

Comment: It's not right, because the Inverse of $\frac{1}{s}$ is $1$, to make it more likeable, but in fact it's totally right!

Answer (score 0):

Notice, for factorization of denominator you should find the roots of quadratic equation: $s^2+4s+8=0$ as $$s=\frac{-4\pm\sqrt{4^2-4(1)(8)}}{2(1)}=-2\pm 2i$$
$$\implies s^2+4s+8=(s+2+2i)(s+2-2i)$$

Now, one should have the following partial fractions  $$X(s)=\frac{10(s+1)}{s(s^2+4s+8)}=\frac{10(s+1)}{s(s+2+2i)(s+2-2i)}$$

$$\frac{10(s+1)}{s(s+2+2i)(s+2-2i)}=\frac{A}{s}+\frac{B}{s+2+2i}+\frac{C}{s+2-2i}$$

Now, you can solve for $A, B$ & $C$ & then apply formula for inverse Laplace for each partial fraction $$L^{-1}\left[\frac{1}{s+a}\right]=e^{-at}$$

Comment: with this way I got, $A=5/4, B = -5/8 + 15/8i, C=B^*= -5/8 - 15/8i$

is it correct

Comment: yes, it is correct if you calculated values carefully.

Comment: if it is correct, than how can I write the final term in term of $cos$ and $sin$

Comment: Alright, notice I write inverse Laplace transform in general form as $$L^{-1}[X(s)]=A L^{-1}\left[\frac{1}{s}\right]+B L^{-1}\left[\frac{1}{s+2+2i}\right]+C L^{-1}\left[\frac{1}{s+2-2i}\right]$$           $$= A \left[1\right]+ B \left[e^{(-2-2 i)t} \right]+ C \left[e^{(-2+2 i)t} \right]$$                                                                                        Now, apply Euler's formula $e^{i\theta}=\cos\theta+i\sin\theta$

Comment: Is it possible to cancel the $s$ with $10s$ and $s$ in denominator in the start?

Comment: No it's not. You just need to take LCM of all partial fractions on RHS  to find unknown constants $A, B, C$ which are free of $s$.

Comment: I mean if I have $$ \frac{10s}{s(s^2+4s+8)} $$ Then can I cancel the $s$ with $10s$ and the $s$ in denominator?

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right

Comment: Ok Than in that case, I will left with:
$$ \frac{10}{(s+2+2i)(s+2-2i)} =   \frac{A}{(s+2+2i)}+ \frac{B}{(s+2-2i)}$$

Correct?

Comment: yes, you are right

Comment: From that I got $A=-\frac{5i}{2}$ and $B=\frac{5i}{2}$